# Survival function for continuous random variables

Tags: probability

I apologize for bad english in advance.

We have the continuous random variable U ~ uniform(0,1) and the continuous random variable Y, that given U = u follows a exponential distribution with parameter (intensity) mu. 
What is the survival function $G_Y(y) = P(Y>y)$?

I have absolutely no clue how to solve this and could therefore use some help getting started.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Law of Total Probability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(Y>y)&=\mathbf{E}\left[\mathbf{P}(Y>y|U)\right] \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbf{P}(Y>y|U=u)1du\quad \text{since $U$ is Uniform$(0,1)$. }
\end{align*}
You should be able to do the rest since you know the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $U=u$.

P.S. use LaTeX to type math.

Comment: Is this correct?
$$ P(Y>y \lvert U = u) = 1-e^{-uy} $$
$$ \int_{0}^{1} 1-e^{-uy} du = \left[u+\frac{1}{y}e^{-uy} \right]^1_0 = 1+ \frac{1}{y}e^{-y}-\frac{1}{y} $$
which gives
$$G_Y(y) = P(Y>y) = 1+\frac{1}{y}(e^{-y}-1)$$
Or is this ^ just $P(Y<y)$ ?

Comment: Wait it should be $P(Y>y \lvert U = u) = 1-(1-e^{-uy})$ because it's the survival function and not the c.d.f, right? 
So I would get 
$$G_Y(y) = P(Y>y) = \frac{1}{y} (1-e^{-y}) $$